# How do you insert data into a dataset then have a message box tell what happened?

Tags: c#, dataset, messagebox

I am having an issue with adding a name to a dataset through a windows form application. Also for some reason beyond me, my message box is not reading my variables. The output for the message box says AddEmployee has been added to the employee directory with the title of AddEmployee. When I check the dataset after I try adding someone it has someone added but the name is AddEmployee and job title is AddEmployee. Here is the code I am trying to get to work.

```
public AddEmployee()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private String employeeName;
    private String jobTitle;

    private void Enter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {string newEmployee = $"{employeeName} has been added to the employee directory with the title of {jobTitle}";
        EmployeeDirectoryDataSetTableAdapters.EmployeeDirectoryTableAdapter EmployeeDirectoryTableAdapter =
        new EmployeeDirectoryDataSetTableAdapters.EmployeeDirectoryTableAdapter();
       
        EmployeeDirectoryTableAdapter.InsertQuery(employeeName, jobTitle);
        textBox1.Text = String.Empty;
        textBox2.Text = String.Empty;
        MessageBox.Show(newEmployee);    
    }
    public void SetName(String Name)
    {
        employeeName = Name;
    }
    public void SetJob(String Job)
    {
        jobTitle = Job;
    }
    private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetName(Text);
    }
    private void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetJob(Text);

    }
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        var newform = new Employee();
        newform.Show();
    }
    private void AddEmployee_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       this.employeeDirectoryTableAdapter.Fill(this.employeeDirectoryDataSet.EmployeeDirectory);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see any declaration nor intialization of the variable `Text`. Where does it come from? and from where does it get its value?

Comment: Thank you Mong Zhu. That fixed it. I figured it was something pretty simple.